# How to return generated UUID primary key

Tags: java, spring, uuid, jdbctemplate

I am working with mySQL database and the table has a primary key in UUID format, generated by the database engine. I am using Spring framework **JdbcTemplate** (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) to perform all operation. But on inserts I do need to return primary key to the caller.
**JdbcTemplate** has method
*public int update(PreparedStatementCreator psc, KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder)*
but it returns integer keys only. **KeyHolder** interface also allow only numeric keys.
Does someone know how to overcome this deficiency? Should I use something other than JdbcTemplate? It is not desirable, but possible.
Give me a hint, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to create UUID in your java in advance and then pass it on to (SQL/DB), so in this case, you already know whats going to be your Primary key. since in theory UUID is unique there should be no collision.

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO users ( user_uuid , first_name , last_name) VALUES (?,?,?)",
                "admin", uuid, user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName());
//uuid: you already have the PrimeryKey in advance
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me!

```java
public String save(SysUser sysUser) {
    String SQL = "INSERT INTO sys_user(id,account_number,telephone,email,real_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL, new String[]{"id"});
        preparedStatement.setString(1, sysUser.getId());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, sysUser.getAccountNumber());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, sysUser.getTelephone());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, sysUser.getEmail());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, sysUser.getRealName());
        return preparedStatement;
    }, keyHolder);
    return String.valueOf(keyHolder.getKeyList().get(0).get("id"));
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way to get a non numeric key

```
GeneratedKeyHolder gendKey = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?) ", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt.setString(1, "val1");
        stmt.setString(2, "val2");
        return stmt;
    }
}, gendKey);

// If multiple rows updated, use getKeys()
String uuid = (String) gendKey.getKey().get("UUID-COL-NAME");
```

Comment: I was not talking about return of the update function. KeyHolder used in the method call allows only numeric value.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/core/KeyHolder
Method getKey return a number.
My primary key is not numeric but UUID.

Comment: My query looks like this:
insert into ITEM_SPECS (ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME, ITEM_VERSION, ITEM_LOCATION, ITEM_OWNER) values (UUID(), ?, ?, ?, ?);
after query execution keyHolder does not contain any keys.
When I started writing this code I planned to use UUID() function as a default value for the key column.  MySQL 5.7 does not support it. Only MySQL 8 does.
Company haven't upgraded to it yet.